# Why the disparity in the Ocean's movies' tags?

Tags: discussion

So, we have [oceans-eleven](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oceans-eleven), [oceans-twelve](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oceans-twelve), and [oceans-thirteen](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oceans-thirteen), and then we have [oceans-8](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oceans-8). This is wrecking my OCD. It also makes it strange to search for the tag (and now knowing how it should be written for the different movies).

Is there some reason for this, or just an accident? Can a mod rename the tag, or should we edit all questions and change their tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The movies appear to be most commonly titled as:

- Ocean's Eleven
- Ocean's Twelve
- Ocean's Thirteen
- Ocean's 8

The Ocean's 8 title is reflected in its

- [Website](http://www.oceans8movie.com/)
- [Poster](https://images.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.impawards.com%2F2018%2Fposters%2Foceans_eight_ver2.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.impawards.com%2F2018%2Foceans_eight_ver2.html&docid=8pFVJ0T6C17pEM&tbnid=5MjG8T-vaXV14M%3A&vet=1&w=509&h=755&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim)
- [Wikipedia listing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean%27s_8) though it indicates it is stylized as Ocean's Eight in the title card
- Review aggregation websites [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/oceans_8/) and [Metacritic](http://www.metacritic.com/movie/oceans-8)

However IMDB has the movie listed under [Ocean's Eight](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5164214/)

So on balance the discrepancy appears to reflect the most commonly viewed title.

I'm not against changing this ... but don't think its entirely compelling since on balance this is how the movie has been represented.  In the meantime to reduce confusion when searching for it I've added the [oceans-eight](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oceans-eight) synonym.

Comment: The new tag solves my issues, and your reasoning is sound